# Is there any way to import files / constants into a json file

Tags: javascript, json, webpack

In my component I want to include a json file of data, so think

```
import slides from './slides-data.json'
```

and slides-data.json looks something like

```
{
  "slides": [
    { img: "img.png", "text": "some text" },
    ...
  ]
}
```

ideally though I would like to import images into a json file like so

```
import MyImage from './assets/img.png'
{
  "slides": [
    { img: "img.png", "text": "some text" },
    ...
  ]
}
```

this is not a valid json, but I am using webpack to handle loaders and was wondering if something like this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write own loader for `slides-data.json` (just example, not tested):

```
module.exports = function(source) {
    this.cacheable();
    JSON.parse(source).slides.forEach(function(slide) {
        this.addDependency(slide.img); // need to resolve this path before adding as dependency
    });
    return source;
};
```

and add loader in config:

```
{test: /slides-data\.json$/, loader: "json-loader!your-custom-slides-loader"}
```

Also you can use own file extension for `slides-data.json`.

---

But firstly check out these links:

[How to write a loader](https://webpack.github.io/docs/how-to-write-a-loader.html)

[Loaders API](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html)